# Direct differentaition

Tags: differential-forms

In a STEP problem I found this: the vector "$\vec r$" is given as below ($a$ and $L$ are constants) and then it said to perform direct differentation to get the second equation.

$$\vec r = a (\sin \theta, \cos \theta) + (L−a\theta)(\cos \theta,− \sin \theta)$$

$$d\vec r = a d\theta (\cos \theta,-\sin \theta) - ad \theta (\cos \theta,-\sin \theta) + (L-a\theta)(-\sin \theta,-\cos\theta)d\theta$$

Would someone explain me what direct differentation means and how did we get the second equation (e.g. where does the second term in the second equation come from)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the vector $\vec r$ given as

$$\vec r = a (\sin \theta, \cos \theta) + (L−a\theta)(\cos \theta,− \sin \theta)$$

we directly differentiate to obtain the differential $d\vec r$ as

$$d\vec r = a \frac{d}{d \theta}(\sin \theta, \cos \theta)d\theta + \frac{d}{d\theta}\left((L−a\theta)(\cos \theta,− \sin \theta)\right)d\theta$$

Now, we use the product rule to differentiate the second term.  This gives

$$d\vec r = a \frac{d}{d \theta}(\sin \theta, \cos \theta)d\theta + \left(\frac{d(L−a\theta)}{d\theta}(\cos \theta,− \sin \theta)+(L−a\theta)\frac{d(\cos \theta,− \sin \theta)}{d\theta}\right)d\theta$$

Carrying out the derivatives gives

$$\begin{align}
d\vec r &= a (\cos \theta, -\sin \theta)d\theta + (-a(\cos \theta,− \sin \theta))d\theta+(L−a\theta)(-\sin \theta,− \cos \theta))d\theta\\\\
&=(L−a\theta)(-\sin \theta,− \cos \theta))d\theta
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think it's should be $\dfrac{\partial (sin \theta, cos \theta)}{\partial \theta} d\theta$

Comment: @LeVanTu Why would one need a partial derivative when there is only one variable?

Comment: i think that the formula $df = \dfrac{df}{dx}dx$ use for the case that $f$ is the function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. here we have the function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: i think is should be like $df= (\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial \theta}+\dfrac{\partial f_2}{\partial\theta})d\theta$

Comment: @levantu That is an incorrect statement.  One does not have a partial derivative. The function of interst is a function of one-parameter, $\theta$, only.  The vector nature does not affect that.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.